# C# : Check value stored inside string object is decimal or not

Tags: c#, decimal

in C# , how can i check whether the value stored inside a string object( Ex :  string strOrderId="435242A") is decimal or not?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) function.

```
decimal value;
if(Decimal.TryParse(strOrderId, out value))
  // It's a decimal
else
  // No it's not.
```

Comment: This will only work if any number can be considered a Decimal.  If you need to distinguish between numeric types, it'll consider integral types as decimals as well.

Comment: You should consider decimal format and current culture. For example, correct decimal value for en-Us 643.57 doesn't parsing in ru-RU culture by this method.

Comment: I know this is old, but I add some extra validations and also check for a decimal comma, witch in my case is the decimal separator.

    `if (!Decimal.TryParse(strOrderId, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimalNumber) || strOrderId.IndexOf(",") > -1)
                                                {
                                                    // not Decimal
                                                }
else {
// decimal
}`

Answer (score 30):

You can use [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) to check if the value can be converted to a Decimal type. You could also use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) instead if you assign the result to a variable of type Double.

MSDN example:

```
string value = "1,643.57";
decimal number;
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
decimal decValue;

if (decimal.TryParse(strOrderID, out decValue)
{ / *this is a decimal */ }
else
{ /* not a decimal */}
```

Answer (score 5):

Take advantage of the discard symbol _ and use

```
if (decimal.TryParse(stringValue, out _))
{
   // valid decimal 
}
else
{
   // not decimal
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you may try parsing it:

```
string value = "123";
decimal result;
if (decimal.TryParse(value, out result))
{
    // the value was decimal
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if we do not want use extra variable.

```
string strOrderId = "435242A";

bool isDecimal = isDecimal(strOrderId);


public bool isDecimal(string value) {

  try {
    Decimal.Parse(value);
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple code will allow integer or decimal value and rejects alphabets and symbols.

```
      foreach (char ch in strOrderId)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != '.')
            {

              MessageBox.Show("This is not a decimal \n");
              return;
            }
           else
           {
           //this is a decimal value
           }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think simple.

```
decimal decNumber = decimal.Parse("9.99");
if (decNumber % 1 > 0)
{
   //decimal area
}
else
{
   //int area
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare decimal out value in TryParse

```
if(Decimal.TryParse(stringValue,out decimal dec))
{
    // ....
}
```