# typeof() to check for Numeric values

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal, typeof

what is the easiest way to check if a typeof() is mathematically usable(numeric).

do i need to use the [TryParse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730838/c-sharp-check-value-stored-inside-string-object-is-decimal-or-not) or check it by this:

```
if (!(DC.DataType == typeof(int) || DC.DataType == typeof(double) || DC.DataType == typeof(long) || DC.DataType == typeof(short) || DC.DataType == typeof(float)))
     {
           MessageBox.Show("Non decimal data cant be calculated");
           return;
     }
```

if there is a more easy way to achieve this, your free to suggest

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828807/what-is-the-base-class-for-c-sharp-numeric-value-types

Comment: What does "mathematically usable" mean? Is an array of doubles mathematically usable, for instace? I think it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .Net, how can I determine if a type is a Numeric ValueType?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124411/using-net-how-can-i-determine-if-a-type-is-a-numeric-valuetype)

Comment: You can achieve the desired result using that method (If you are checking for a number). Remember int, long, short aren't decimal compatible.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov after reading the link of ShadowWizard i found out i was meaning numeric types, not decimal, i will edit my post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing much to do, unfortunately. But from C# 3 onwards, you can do something fancier:

```
public static class NumericTypeExtension
{
    public static bool IsNumeric(this Type dataType)
    {
        if (dataType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataType");

        return (dataType == typeof(int)
                || dataType == typeof(double)
                || dataType == typeof(long)
                || dataType == typeof(short)
                || dataType == typeof(float)
                || dataType == typeof(Int16)
                || dataType == typeof(Int32)
                || dataType == typeof(Int64)
                || dataType == typeof(uint)
                || dataType == typeof(UInt16)
                || dataType == typeof(UInt32)
                || dataType == typeof(UInt64)
                || dataType == typeof(sbyte)
                || dataType == typeof(Single)
               );
    }
}
```

so your original code can be written like this:

```
if (!DC.DataType.IsNumeric())
{
      MessageBox.Show("Non decimal data cant be calculated");
      return;
}
```

Comment: these are all the known numeric types? (except char) of are there more?

Comment: No, this is a subset. For a comprehensive list, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182747/126052) from another topic. I may update my answer later.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the interfaces that the numeric types implement:

```
if (data is IConvertible) {
  double value = ((IConvertible)data).ToDouble();
  // do calculations
}

if (data is IComparable) {
  if (((IComparable)data).CompareTo(42) < 0) {
    // less than 42
  }
}
```